# Creating a subset from a dataframe based on a specific policy number

Tags: r, subset

So I have this dataframe of policies, of which one of the columns are policy numbers, among other columns such as smoking status, etc.

I can create subsets of the dataframe using specific values for all other columns except policy number.

For e.g., `dataframe$somker_status==1` returns some `'TRUE'` and some `'FALSE'`, as expected. But when I try this for `dataframe$policy_number==4646864`, say, it returns `'FALSE'` for all, even though there is a policy in the dataframe with the policy number equal to `4646864`.

I don't know why this is happening, can anyone help?

[Screenshot of my workspace image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9f0N.png)

EDIT: I have found the problem. Thanks @Biranjan! Changing the data type from double to integer seems to have done the trick

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. I will also recommend to take a look at this post; [_how do I ask a good question_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's generally good to demonstrate you already put some effort into it.

Comment: Have you checked if the data type of column **policy_number** is an integer?

Comment: @EricFail I'm not sure how to add an example?

Comment: @Biranjan It doesn't reflect as an integer, it reflects as "double"

Comment: @U.Ismail  check out `dput()` for help with preparing the example.

Comment: @U.Ismail, did you read the articles I linked? Please take a look at them for how to add a complete minimal reproducible example. Also, as Aramis7d points out, `dput()` is often a handy tool.

Comment: Double is still a numeric type so it is not because of the comparison between a wrong data types. So unless there is a reproducible example I guess we can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: @EricFail Thanks I will keep that in mind for the next time I need to ask something.

Comment: @Biranjan I know Double is a numeric type but it wasn't allowing me to refer to rows by policy number. Once I used as.integer(pol_number) it worked!

Comment: @U.Ismail, I suggest you add a small reproducible example and your solution as an answer. That would improve this post by making it useful for others who might fun into a similar issue. Glad you solved your issue.

Comment: @EricFail There wasn't a problem. The problem was me not noticing that the policy numbers had decimal points to them. As the decimal points were not in my view, when I tried to refer to specific policies by policy number I forgot to add the decimal points. Hence the entire issue